# What are the available tools for debugging CSS?

Tags: css, debugging

I'm beginner in web development, I wonder what are the available tools for debugging CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt to cover all browsers (which I have used):

- [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) A bookmarklet, works in IE6!
- [Fireug Firefox plugin](http://getfirebug.com/), original but firefox can be slower to load (I find)
- Webkit developer tools (Chrome and Safari)

  - Chrome: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html
  - Safari: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

Personally i find myself in the Chrome developer tools, developing on a Macbook, whereas I used to be a solely Firebug tester, but then my goal is not to test in all browsers (as it should be) but rather to just get it working in the browsers I care about!

Answer (score 4):

The most valuable tool I've run across is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Some [other](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) [browsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also come with developer tools built-in these days.

Comment: just to add that firebug it's an addon of firefox

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is generally considered the best in debugging HTML/CSS problems.

Safari and Google Chrome's built in Webkit Developer Tools are also pretty good.

There are also developer tools for Internet Explorer if it's a browser-specific issue, but they're not as powerful or easy to use as Firebug or Webkit's Developer Tools.